# productFlavors application Id

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-build-type, android-build-flavors, android-buildconfig

I'm trying to make two types of builds in Android Studio usung `productFlavors`.
I need to have unique applicationId for each buld type.
And here is an issue:

First of all I add this code to my gradle file

```
productFlavors {
    base {
        applicationId "ru.Public.lib"
    }

    city {
        applicationId "ru.Public.lib.city"
    }
```

Then when I'm trying to build app with city type, Android Studio shows an error:

```
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processBaseDebugGoogleServices'.
No matching client found for package name 'ru.Public.lib.debug'"
```

After this I decided that I need to change package name at my Manifest file.
I tryed to change package name in Manifest by three ways:

1. In project structure I created new Manifest app > src > city > AndroidManifest.xml. At this file I use `package="ru.Public.lib.city"`
2. I didn't create a new Manifest. Instead of it I used a placehilder for package name like this: `package="${applicationId}"`
3. I combined these two methods: "using placeholder at new Manifest in app > src > city >"

All shown ways gives me an error in the Manifest:  Android Studio colored activity names by red and says `unsolved class 'Activity Name'`

Here is a part of my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.Public.lib">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name="ru.Public.lib.app.Application"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarDefault">

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ActivityMain"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ActivityEdition"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">

        </activity>
.....................................................................etc.
</manifest>
```

So. It looks like I need to recreate all my acivities in new directories acording to every packege name I need. But it is too complicated way. I'm sure that Google solved this problem.

Do anybody have some ideas about this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some step to solve it.

> 1. Go to your firebase console
> 2. Select your previous project and Add another app
> 3. Register another applicationId (Register all of your applicationID one by one)
> 4. Then Download new `google-services.json`
> 5. And place new `google-services.json` in your project

Thats it